# Use code to automatically fill the form of a content type

Tags: forms, nodes

I have a content type called Event. I advertise events on my [website](http://etraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/node/add/event) using this form.
I want to advertise automatically using code.
I have this code which when I run automatically add content. But at the moment it adds the title and the body.

```
ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node = new stdClass();
//print_r($node);
$title          =  "test post 3";// html_entity_decode($_POST['title']);
// $summary     =   "summarry";//$_POST['summary'];      
$body           =  "This is testing of Automated Script";// $_POST['body']; 
$node->uid      = '0'; //author
$node->type     = 'event';    //content type
// $node->created  = time() - (rand( 1,240) * 60); 
$node->created  = strtotime("now");
$node->changed  = strtotime("now"); 
$node->field_location = 'Oxford';
$node->title    = $title;
$node->status   = 0;
$node->promote  = 0;
$node->sticky   = 0;
$node->language = 'und';
$node->body['und'][0]['value']   = $body;
// $node->body['und'][0]['summary'] = $summary;
$node->body['format']  = 'full_html';
node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
print "ok";
```

How do I add remaining inputs like City, Country, Event Date, Duration, Email Address using code?

[image: Event content type showing machine names]

Comment: Have those fields been added to the content type? And where data will come?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! On Stack Exchange, questions and answers are kept separated. You can answer your own question, but you need to write an answer, not editing the question. Also, we don't normally change the title to say the issue has been resolved; that is what accepting answers is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do something similar to what you do to set the body of the note for each of your additional field (City, Country, Event Date, Duration, Email Address). The exact data structure for each filed depends on its type.

The general pattern is

```
$node->{$field_machine_name}[$language][0] = array(...);
```

The *hard* part if figuring the content of the `array(...)` which is the value of the field. The value of a field is actually always an associative array. Its keys (also called columns) depend on the type of the field. A text field, for instance, as only one `value` key/column. A taxonomy term reference field has also only one key/column, but named `tid`.

For instance your city and duration field are a simple text fields whose machine names are `field_location` and `field_duration` you can set their values with

```
$node->field_location['und'][0] =  array('value' => 'Oxford');
$node->field_duration['und'][0] =  array('value' => '2');
```

You country field is a Taxonomy Term Reference field, its value can be set with

```
$node->field_country['und'][0] = array('tid' => 1);
```

Where `1` is the ID of a term in the proper taxonomy vocabulary.

If you were using an single [address field](https://drupal.org/project/addressfield) name `field_location` to store the location, the code should be something like

```
$node->field_location['und'][0] = array(
  'country' => 'GB',
  'locality' =>  'Oxford',
);
```

The structure to set a [date field](https://drupal.org/project/date) depends on the date format. If the field uses the ISO format, you can set it with something like

```
$node->field_date['und'][0] =  array(
  // The start date.
  'value' => '2014-04-02T10:00:00',
  // The end date.
  'value2' => '2014-04-02T11:00:00',
);
```

To *discover* the structure of a field, I suggest to use the [Devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel). It provides a *devel* tab on node that let you explore the structure of the `$node` object for an existing node. You can also check the [`hook_field_schema()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_schema/7) implementation of the module defining the field type.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code to add custom fields:

```
$node->field_city[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'London';
$node->field_county[$node->language][0]['value'] = 'England';
```

I find the easiest way to make sure you are using the correct structure is to create a node using the back-end UI, and then inspect it with the [devel module](https://drupal.org/project/devel). This will show you the correct field names to use.

Also not all fields use 'value'.

For example a taxonomy relation field would use:

```
$node->field_taxonomy_reference[$node->language][0]['tid'] = 189;
```

Or an entity reference field would use:

```
$node->field_entity_reference[$node->language][0]['target_id'] = 189;
```

For some other examples see these blog posts [How to programmatically create node in drupal 7](http://www.lightrains.com/blog/programmatically-create-node-drupal-7) or [Creating and Updating Nodes Programmatically in Drupal 7](http://www.group42.ca/creating_and_updating_nodes_programmatically_in_drupal_7).